# JavaScript/jQuery inquiries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict";

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var homePageHeight = $('#main').height();

    if (windowHeight >= homePageHeight){
        $('#main').css("padding-top", (((windowHeight-homePageHeight)/2))-130);
        $('#main').css("padding-bottom", (((windowHeight-homePageHeight)/2))-130);
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {       
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var homePageHeight = $('#main').height();

        if (windowHeight >= homePageHeight){
            $('#main').css("padding-top", ((windowHeight-homePageHeight)/2));
            $('#main').css("padding-bottom", ((windowHeight-homePageHeight)/2));
        }
    });
```

Basically I have a section here on my HTML that handled by that code above:

```
<section id="main">
</section>
```

I understand that these codes handles the size of the screen on the top but can anyone help me understand in layman's term how does the `windowHeight and homePageHeight` works? You simply explain it to me each function on the top line by line if that's possible.

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. What are you unable to understand? What do you mean by *"how does the `windowHeight` and `homePageHeight` works"* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(window).height();` assigned to `windowHeight` is height of the (browser) window or viewport. With respect to the web browsers the viewport here is visible portion.

`$('#main').height();` assigned to `homePageHeight` is height of the div or section identified by ID `main`

`(windowHeight >= homePageHeight)` checks whether browser height is greater than height of section #main

if `windowHeight` greater than or equal to `homePageHeight`, then a padding is added to top and bottom of #main

```
$('#main').css("padding-top", (((windowHeight-homePageHeight)/2))-130);
$('#main').css("padding-bottom", (((windowHeight-homePageHeight)/2))-130);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/). The function `height()` is your favourite. 
The measured height = (Height of Element) - (margin + border-width + padding of Element)

Comment: I understand that The height() method sets or returns the height of the selected elements.. Can you explain each line in layman's term how does the codes works especially that lines.

Answer (score 0):

`windowHeight` is a variable, it's value is being set to the height of the browser window.

`homePageHeight` is also a variable, it's value is being set to the height of `div#main`.

When the document loads, it's checking if `windowHeight` is greater than or equal to `homePageHeight`; if it returns true, it is applying some css using jQuery.

When the window resizes, it's doing a similar thing again.

The rest of the code is very self-explanatory. If you still do not understand it, you need to read up on [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) and [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/).